# Como obter a URL de uma foto do Firebase Storage?

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Bom dia a todos, estou com uma dificuldade em capturar a URL de uma determinada foto que é enviada ao firebase storage. O cadastro de cliente funciona perfeitamente, o upload da imagem também é feito corretamente. Então eu passo para a variável cliente.foto receber o myPhotoURL que armazena a URL da foto, porém não está salvando no banco de dados, então não conseguirei exibir a foto posteriormente.

```
  //função do upload de fotos
  private uploadPhoto(): void {
   this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.png')
   .putString(this.Picture, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/png' })
   .then((savedPicture) => {
    //aqui a myPhotoURL recebe a URL da foto
    this.myPhotoURL = savedPicture.downloadURL;
  });
 }


//função de cadastro de cliente
adicionarCliente() {
  this.cliente.clienteFinalizado = true;
  this.clienteProvider.adicionarCliente(this.cliente);
  //faz o upload da foto 
  this.uploadPhoto();
  //após upload concluído, a variável foto recebe a URL da foto no storage
  this.cliente.foto  = this.myPhotoURL;
  this.toastCadastro();
 }
```

Comment: Estou usando IONIC3

Comment: Você está salvando os dados do cliente após alterar `cliente.foto`? Também leve em consideração que `putString` é assíncrono

Comment: Fiz alguns ajustes no código, porém ainda continuo recebendo undefined..Não me retorna a URL da foto cadastrada

Comment: Coloque as duas últimas linhas da segunda função dentro de um `setTimeout` de 3s, funcionou como esperado?

Comment: este código sempre me retorna undefined, já fiz diversos testes e ainda assim não consegui sair do lugar, por conta do undefined. Consegui achar um outro código, porém me retorna isto no console.

    Firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sacola-aplicativo.appspot.com/o/Fotos- 
    Clientes%2Ff7d6d5dc-4a07-4627-b2e7%2FmyPhoto.png:1 GET 
    https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sacola- 
    aplicativo.appspot.com/o/Fotos-Clientes%2Ff7d6d5dc-4a07-4627- 
    b2e7%2FmyPhoto.png 404 (Not Found)